# ComponentModel Display resource by reflection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection

I'm localizing my asp.net Mvc app. The strings are placed in resource files. I'm decorating my models with the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute attribute like for example:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ModelRes.User), Name = "LogonName")]
    public virtual string LogonName { get; set; }
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(ModelRes.User), Name = "Password")]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I have one resource file per model(class), and the User.resx looks like this:

```
LogonName | "Logon name"
Password  | "Password"
```

Now imagine that for a lot of properties, you get the idea. What I would like to do instead is this:

```
[CustomDisplay(typeof(ModelRes.User))]
public class User
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string LogonName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and still be able to use this in my (razor) view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LogonName)
```

Any experiences with implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write a custom [ModelMetadataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407387.aspx).

Then you will have to set the [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.displayname.aspx) property of the `ModelMetadata` variable using your custom attribute and property name.

Here are some examples/tutorials

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Service Location, Part 7: Model Metadata](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt7-model-metadata.html)

[Customizing ASP.NET MVC 2 Metadata and Validation](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx)